# A simple-looking rational limit

Tags: calculus, limits, rational-functions

Please help me compute:
$$
\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{2(z-\log(1+z))}}{z}
$$
I know the answer is 1 because I plugged it into *Mathematica*. Attempts with L'Hopital's Rule didn't work. This a step in an exercise for my self-study project. Thanks!

Comment: ??  According to the WolframAlpha limit does not exist: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto+0%7D+%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%7B2%28x-%5Clog%281%2Bx%29%29%7D%7D%7Bx%7D

Comment: Yes @georg you are right because for negative $z$'s limit can't be $1$.

Comment: You guys are right, I should have added sign(z) to the numerator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Taylor series
$$\log (1+z)\sim_0 z-\frac{z^2}{2}$$
we get

$$\frac{\sqrt{2(z-\log(1+z))}}{z}\sim_0\frac{|z|}{z}\sim\left\{\begin{array}[cc]\\1\;&\text{at}\; 0^+\\-1\;&\text{at}\; 0^-\end{array}\right.$$
so the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

$$\log(1+z)=z-\frac{z^2}2+\frac{z^3}3-\cdots$$

So, $$z-\log(1+z)=\frac{z^2}2-\frac{z^3}3+\cdots$$

Comment: Thanks Lab. If you have time, could you please write out a formal justification for switching $\lim$ and $\sum$ in $\lim_{z\to 0}\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{z^{n-2}(-1)^n}{n}$? I am guessing it likely involves uniform convergence but my calculus is so rusty at the moment, I can't write a neat justification myself.

Answer (score 1):

Apply L'Hopital's rule to the square of the function:
$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{2(z-\log(1+z))}{z^2}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{2(1-\frac{1}{1+z})}{2z}=\cdots=1\ .$$
See if you can fill in the working and then finish your problem for $z\to0^+$.

In fact, if you look carefully at the limit as $z\to0^-$ you will find it is different.  So the (proper, "two-sided") limit does not exist.